# Sub range selection behavior confusing when evaluating For Each

Tags: excel, vba

Using the code below I'm trying to set those fields that are lime green to the value of the column header. The confusing behavior is that once it fills the first several fields that are filled with lime green it will never again fill a lime green field with the value of rCell(0). What is causing the evaluation of rCell to change? I would expect it to remain static as the selection doesn't change. I've confirmed the sub correctly matches the subsequent lime green fields (as the color is replaced) but the code just doesn't write the header value at that point. For now I've worked around the behavior by setting the header value to a separate string before the for each loop but I'd like to understand where I'm getting lost & losing the selection of the range.

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim rCell As Range
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Select the range to be processed."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each rCell In Selection
        If rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then  'lime green
            rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)      'white
            rCell.Value = rCell(0).Value
        End If
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: rcell is one cell in the Selection.  I assume that you want `rCell.Value = Selection(0).Value`  But for this to work the Header value needs to be in the cell directly above the cells selected.

Comment: Thanks, so I get it now. Since the previous Cell had already been filled from the field before it everything would work fine until something wasn't filled with lime green. The subsequent sections wouldn't fill with a value even though they were matched because I wasn't really referencing the header in the first place.

Comment: You may also want to add a test that the first row in the sheet is not part of the selection as `Selection(0).Value` will throw an error.

Comment: It was a part of the selection but I've modified the sub to not select the header and used your method anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

The line `rCell.Value = rCell(0).Value` wasn't referencing the header value as thought, it was referencing the cell above the the current location within the evaluation of the range. As Scott Craner notes above I want to reference the value before the selection by using `rCell.Value = Selection(0).Value`.